# Use of + or . in the username part of email addresses

Tags: firebase-authentication

Is there a way to make firebase authentication consider the following email addresses as equal for the purpose of signing up or logging in a (new) user?

> - imauser@gmail.com
> - imauser+test@gmail.com
> - im.a.user@gmail.com
> - im.a.user+test@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication intentionally does not normalize the `+suffix` our of the email address, as this is used in certain regions to allow multiple users to share a single account.

This behavior is not configurable, so if you want to map these accounts, you will have to filter it in your application code before calling the Firebase API to sign the user up or in.